# How to lambdify elliptic functions in sympy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, ipython, sympy

I want to use the elliptic function embedded in the sympy library, but something is wrong when I try to lambdify elliptic(f(z)), where f is a symbolic function:

```
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np

r = sym.S('r')
_f = 500.0*r
f=sym.lambdify(r,_f,'numpy')

f(np.arange(0,1.1,0.1) )
```

The ouput is correct:

```
array([   0.,   50.,  100.,  150.,  200.,  250.,  300.,  350.,  400.,
    450.,  500.])
```

Then I try a f2(f(r)):

```
_f2 = _f/10
f2= sym.lambdify(r,_f2,'numpy')

f2(np.arange(0,1.1,0.1) )
```

And it works:

```
array([  0.,   5.,  10.,  15.,  20.,  25.,  30.,  35.,  40.,  45.,  50.])
```

But when I try:

```
_ek=sym.elliptic_k(_f)
ek=sym.lambdify(r,_ek,'numpy')

ek(0)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-17-35ab6a3fc36f>", line 1, in <module>
EK(0)

File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>

NameError: name 'elliptic_k' is not defined
```

Any ideas how to solve it? Of course I would like to not rewrite all the elliptic_k functions if possible.
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sympy.functions.elliptic_k perhaps?

Comment: There is no such function.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the documentation of lambdify:

`Attention: Functions that are not in the math module will throw a name                    error when the lambda function is evaluated!`.

Thus you need to pass to `lambdify` the name of the corresponding module (which is `sympy` and not `numpy` for the `elliptic_k` function).

```
ek=sym.lambdify(r,_ek,'sympy')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't notice that! :)

Answer (score 1):

NumPy does not have elliptic functions, but [SciPy does](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ellipk.html#scipy.special.ellipk). `lambdify` does not yet include SciPy functions automatically, so you'll need to do

```
lambdify(r, _ek, modules=['numpy', {'elliptic_k': scipy.special.ellipk}])
```

See [the lambdify documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify) for more information.